# Item Field returning value with hash character in Itemupdate

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, splistitem

I am trying to get value of item field from the list. The field is a lookup field with integer value. When I am trying get the value it is coming like `9;#9` (shown below). But I need only `9`.

[image]

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPList list = web.Lists["Project/Task Status Details"];
SPListItem item = properties.List.GetItemByIdSelectedFields(properties.ListItem.ID, "Project_x002f_Task_x0020_Status_");
int details = (int)item["Project_x002f_Task_x0020_Status_"];//Error here
```

How get only value of it? not with hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default, a lookup field contains just one value. In this case, the
>   field value is an object of type String, and the string has the
>   following format: Id;#Value

Use `int value = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["Project_x002f_Task_x0020_Status_"] as String).LookupValue` to read the lookup value 
and `int id = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["Project_x002f_Task_x0020_Status_"] as String).LookupId` to read the Id.